# Ui views not updating

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I am using majidgolshadi/Android-Download-Manager-Pro lib for downloading some files but I am facing some issues to show a progress bar. I try to resolve it by runonui thread method but when I press back button and again open the downloader activity downloading process is working but UI update stopped working

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                p.setText(String.valueOf(GlobalValue.progressPer));
                Log.e("****","getTag:---1 "+ p.getTag());
               // Log.e("****","backThread:----2 "+msg);
            }
        });
```